# How to reach the parent object?

Tags: object-oriented, c++, composition

I have a parent object that has some other objects as fields. The parent object fully owns these fields: they can be declared as fields of the parent object (`MyPart part`), directly, not as references.

I would prefer to initialize these fields in constructor, but in some cases they do need to reach the parent object instance and call methods on it as they work. With raw pointers, I could simply pass `this` to they constructors or setters. I have just discovered however that creating smart pointer from `this` is something near impossible, because such pointer would not know when the parent object goes out of scope (for sure not where the constructor returns!). But I do known that being the fields of the parent object, these children definitely cannot outlive it.

The only "clean" idea I can so far imagine is to construct the object in some factory method where reference to the constructed parent can be a smart pointner, then construct children separately and use the setter to compose the parent. Is this really the best approach?

As we have now policy to avoid raw pointers at all costs, what other options could I have? Or just using raw pointers in such a case is appropriate?

Comment: Use a reference `Parent&`, and pass it `*this` if you truly need access to the parent. If the child needs access to the parent through a `std::shared_ptr<>`, you can have the parent inherit `std::enable_shared_from_this` [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this). This will allow a `shared_ptr` to be constructed by `this->shared_from_this()`. Unless you are implementing a data structure this is almost certainly poorly designed. Whatever `child` needs of `Parent` try and extract it into a common class, this way it can be fully constructed before use.

Comment: Raw pointers shouldn’t *own* data (because you could forget to delete them), but it’s fine to use them to reference data or to access data.

Comment: A policy to "avoid raw pointers _at all costs_" may have been well-intentioned - but it is controversial, and in modern C++, unnecessary as the use of a raw pointer now has a definite meaning: This pointer _does not own the object pointed to_.  With that meaning there is no ambiguity about whether you should free (i.e., delete) one or not: You shouldn't.  [Here are B. Stroustrup's arguments for dropping _observer_ptr_ - which was intended for this kind of thing - and just using raw pointer notation (pdf).](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1408r0.pdf)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a reference to the parent. As a sketch

```
class Parent;

class Child {
private: 
    Parent & parent;
public:
    Child(Parent & p) : parent(p) {}
    // other members
};

class Parent {
private:
    Child child;
public:
    Parent() : child(*this) {}
    // other members
};
```

As a bonus, the compiler will refuse to let you construct a `Child` without a `Parent`. You can go further, and make `Child` only privately constructable, and friend `Parent`.

Comment: The problem with using a reference is that `Child` is not assignable anymore. Using a pointer member variable avoids that.

Comment: @DDrmmr? it's a subobject of `Parent`, it doesn't need to be assignable

Comment: Bracket missing at the start of `Parent`. =)

Comment: Reference as member is only valid during the expression which created it. It is a cause of undefined behavior in the next valid expression. It is not because the referenced object goes out of scope, it is just the rule of the language. This needs to be handled using pointers or copy semantics instead. There is an entire paragraph describing the UB caused by keeping member reference in 14882:2003 that I'm too lazy to search for.

Comment: @nurettin `child` is created with a valid reference to the `Parent` object, and is destroyed strictly before the `Parent`. Did you miss the part where `child` is a data member of the `Parent` object?

Comment: @Caleth no no it all looks ok it's just a limitation of the language it just doesn't let you keep references as member variables after the expression you've called the constructor at.

Comment: @nurettin you are flat incorrect. I'm not sure what lifetime issue you are thinking of, but this example isn't it

Comment: @nurettin It sounds like you are thinking of temporary materialisation in const references? Firstly `Child` is taking a mutable reference, and secondly it can't outlive the referent

Comment: @nurettin Do you think the language would permit member references *at all* if there were *no* safe uses?

Comment: @Caleth There are safe uses, you can use it in the builder pattern where you return a reference to *this and call member functions until you execute one last function that returns a different instance all within the same expression. But since I haven't proven my claim using a reference to the standard this is just moot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131689/discussion-between-caleth-and-nurettin).

Answer (score 13):

Just use a raw pointer, it is a non-owning pointer that has no implication on life-cycle.

And the child holding a parent pointer will not outlive the parent as you say they are non-pointer/reference members so parent will clean them up.

Answer (score 8):

Try to avoid coupling the field classes to the parent class. Any data that is in the parent, but is needed by the field, can be passed when calling a function of the field. Any function of the parent that needs to be called by a function of the field can be passed as a callback function (e.g. using `std::function`).

A mutual dependency between classes is often an indication that the code is ill structured. The flow of the program can quickly become unwieldy, making the code hard to maintain.

If the field really needs a reference to the parent, you can safely pass the `this` pointer to the field's constructor (even in the parent's initializer list), provided the field's constructor doesn't access the passed pointer, but only stores it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use mix of non-const reference and [non-static data member initialization](https://www.bfilipek.com/2015/02/non-static-data-members-initialization.html#nsdmi-non-static-data-member-initialisation).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Parent;
class Child {
private:
    Parent& parent;
public:
    Child(Parent& parent): parent(parent) { cout << "Child ctor" << endl; };
    ~Child() { cout << "Child dtor" << endl; } ;
};

class Parent {
private:
    Child child { Child(*this) };
public:
    Parent (){ cout << "Parent ctor" << endl; };
    ~Parent() { cout << "Parent dtor" << endl; } ;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Parent parent;
}
```

output:

```
~$ g++ -o test test.cpp -std=c++11 && ./test
Child ctor
Parent ctor
Parent dtor
Child dtor
```